# SwiftUI View re-renders before model updates

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Why is my view rendering the model update, before the update has completed? Or at least it seems that way. It seems like, it re-draws based on the previous value of my model.

What I'm doing: When you tap a person cell, it marks that person as "selected" and then changes the foreground color to green. If they are not selected, the foreground color is white.

What is happening: It is important to note that this doesn't ALWAYS happen. It seems random. But occasionally, when I tap on a person cell, the color does not change. And I've dug deeper, and that is because it (looks like) it redraws the view before the value has changed inside my `PeopleStore` model object.

Here is the code:

```
struct PersonCell: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var peopleStore: PeopleStore
    var personId: UUID
    
    var person: Person {
        return peopleStore.people.filter({ $0.id == personId }).first!
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print("Tapped Cell: " + peopleStore.personName(id: personId))
            peopleStore.toggleSelectionOfPerson(with: personId)
        }) {
            GeometryReader { geo in
                ZStack {
                    Rectangle().foregroundColor(peopleStore.personIsSelected(id: personId) ? .tGreen : .white).cornerRadius(geo.size.width / 2).frame(height: 70)
```

Here is what happens when I tap a cell:

```
class PeopleStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people : [Person]
    
    init(people: [Person]){
        self.people = people
    }
    
    func personIsSelected(id: UUID) -> Bool {
        let index = people.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        print("ZSTACK: \(people[index].name) is selected: \(people[index].isSelected.description)")
        return people[index].isSelected
    }
    
    func toggleSelectionOfPerson(with id: UUID) {
        let index = people.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        print("BEFORE \(people[index].name) is selected: \(people[index].isSelected.description)")
        people[index].isSelected = !people[index].isSelected
        print("AFTER \(people[index].name) is selected: \(people[index].isSelected.description)")
    }
```

And when I look at my console, you can see that after I select a person, the view redraws, but it has the previous value (In this case, I tapped the Alexandra cell):

```
Tapped Cell: Alexandra R.
BEFORE Alexandra R. is selected: false
ZSTACK: Jose G. is selected: false
ZSTACK: Jimmy T. is selected: false
ZSTACK: Alexandra R. is selected: false
ZSTACK: Dominic R. is selected: false
AFTER Alexandra R. is selected: true
ZSTACK: Franny E. is selected: false
ZSTACK: Jon B. is selected: true
```

ZStack: is printed whenever the cell is re-drawn. As you can see, Alexandra is selected: false shows up, when I would expect it to be true.

The timing of the re-draw seems to be just a bit off, and it seems random. What am I missing?

EDIT: Person struct

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var photo: Image
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var dateFavorited = Date()
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}
```

Edit 2: If it helps, the PersonCell is a subview of something called a PersonList that uses ForEach to generate PersonCells.

```
struct PeopleList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var peopleStore: PeopleStore
    var title: String {
        return isFavorites ? "Favorites" : "All Employees"
    }
    var isFavorites: Bool

    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            Text(title).padding(.top, 18).padding(.horizontal, 5).font(.regular())
            if isFavorites {
                ForEach(peopleStore.people.sorted(by: { $0.dateFavorited < $1.dateFavorited }).filter({ $0.isFavorite })) { person in
                    PersonCell(personId: person.id).frame(height: 70.0)
                }
```

Comment: “it redraws the view before the value has changed inside my PeopleStore model object”, subscribed views will re-draw only when publisher fires an update on property changes. There has to be something else happening in your code, I think you need to share more details.

Comment: I added the Person struct.  if it helps, the person cell is a subview of something called a PersonList that uses ForEach to generate PersonCells.

Comment: you have EnvironmentObject in PeopleList as well, when you click button in ChildCell and it updates property in model, PeopleList view will also refresh.

Comment: Do you propose an alternative?

Comment: In PersonCell just try with "var peopleStore: PeopleStore”, and test once.

Comment: Didn't work. Looks like it needs to be an @EnvironmentObject in order to know that it should re-draw

Comment: It is probably the `person` to `title`vcomputed property. since you are filtering every time the property is accessed. It isn't observing changes just recalculating when accessed if the timing between the `body` redrawing and the trigger and the time it takes to filter.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly is going wrong at your end, i have tested your code at my end and it’s working perfectly fine. The only change I have done is set `var isFavorites: Bool = true` in `PeopleList` because i don’t know how you are toggling that property in your code.So, I have provided it a constant value.

Below is the code -:

```
struct Person: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
    var photo: Image
    var isFavorite: Bool
    var dateFavorited = Date()
    var isSelected: Bool = false
}

class PeopleStore: ObservableObject {
    @Published var people : [Person]
    
    init(people: [Person]){
        self.people = people
    }
    
    func personIsSelected(id: UUID) -> Bool {
        let index = people.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        print("ZSTACK: \(people[index].name) is selected: \(people[index].isSelected.description)")
        return people[index].isSelected
    }
    
    func personName(id: UUID) -> String {
        let index = people.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        return people[index].name
    }
    
    func toggleSelectionOfPerson(with id: UUID) {
        let index = people.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!
        print("BEFORE \(people[index].name) is selected: \(people[index].isSelected.description)")
        people[index].isSelected = !people[index].isSelected
        print("AFTER \(people[index].name) is selected: \(people[index].isSelected.description)")
    }
}

struct PeopleList: View {
    @EnvironmentObject var peopleStore:PeopleStore
    
    var title: String {
        return isFavorites ? "Favorites" : "All Employees"
    }
    var isFavorites: Bool = true
    
    var filteredPersons:[Person]{
        peopleStore.people.sorted(by: { $0.dateFavorited < $1.dateFavorited }).filter({ $0.isFavorite })
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 15) {
            Text(title).padding(.top, 18)
            if isFavorites {
                ForEach(filteredPersons) { person in
                    PersonCell(personId: person.id).frame(height: 70.0)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct PersonCell: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var peopleStore:PeopleStore
    var personId: UUID
    
    var body: some View {
        
            Button(action: {
                print("Tapped Cell: " + peopleStore.personName(id: personId))
                peopleStore.toggleSelectionOfPerson(with: personId)
            }) {
                GeometryReader { geo in
                    ZStack {
                        Rectangle().foregroundColor(peopleStore.personIsSelected(id: personId) ? .green : .gray).cornerRadius(geo.size.width / 2).frame(height: 70)
                    }
                }
            
        }
    }
}
```

Main View-:

```
import SwiftUI

@main
struct Test: App {
    
    @StateObject var store:PeopleStore
    
    init() {
        let person = Person(name: "foo", photo: Image(""), isFavorite: true)
        let person1 = Person(name: "foo1", photo: Image(""), isFavorite: true)
        let person2 = Person(name: "foo2", photo: Image(""), isFavorite: true)
        let obj = PeopleStore(people: [person,person1,person2])
        
        _store = StateObject(wrappedValue: obj)
    }
    
    var body: some Scene {
            WindowGroup {
                PeopleList().environmentObject(store)
            }
        }
}
```

**Output-:**

```
Tapped Cell: foo
BEFORE foo is selected: false
AFTER foo is selected: true
ZSTACK: foo2 is selected: false
ZSTACK: foo is selected: true
ZSTACK: foo1 is selected: false
```

**Note-:** I have tested multiple times, and didn’t found any issue where selected cell isn’t changing color.